# Who translated "CEO's Wife So Sweet"?

Tags: translation, chinese-language

[*CEO's Wife So Sweet*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/CEO_s_Wife_So_Sweet/ZSL7DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) This seems to be an online novel series originally written in Chinese.

The language in the translated end product seems stilted and unnatural to say the least. I am wondering about the translator. Google Books lists Lemon Novel as the translator. Is it a translation company? I think it's safe to assume the translator is not a native speaker(s) of English. I wonder if the online fiction series is machine translated.

Comment: Most probably, this is machine-*generated*.

Comment: @Yorik You mean the original Chinese text was machine-generated?

Comment: No, I mean there was no original text; this is a "fake book" generated by a computer. It isn't a poor translation, it is incoherent babble without any structure. The book cover also looks (so-called) AI generated. E-publishing/self-publishing outlets are rife with fake books at this point. (bear in mind these are bot-submitted and unvetted; as opposed to compilations that humans select for praise)

Comment: @Yorik Interesting. I am not well versed in e-publishing or online fiction. I didn't know AI had improved so much that it was now wholesale generating literature! I will have to look into that. But it does seem to be a different case in the Chinese circle. A Chinese friend has just helped track down the Chinese original. I won't put up a link here because it's on an app and behind a subscription wall. But in this case, there seems to be a real Chinese author responsible for penning those books.

Comment: @EddieKal Machine-generated literature is [definitely a thing](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1275/17) (even if ultimately not relevant to this question).